# I have NEC laptop that have 7A/125V power cable with us plug and want to use us to eu plug adapter

Tags: laptop, power, adapter

First of all, I lived in Indonesia, so I'm sorry if my English is a bit confusing.

I bought a japan used laptop that is sell in online store. and I got 7A/125V us plug power cable and 100~240V/1.8A 50-60Hz AC Adapter. we use eu socket here, so i buy a us to eu plug adapter with rated voltage 220V and current voltage 2.5A.

Is it safe to use the adapter? I worry cause just realized that the amp in it is lower than the amp in the cable

My power cable similar like this:

[image: my power cable similar like this]

The adapter that I bought:

[image: the adapter that I bought]

My AC adapter:

[image: my AC adapter]

Comment: Get the adapter for your laptop. It should be one plug, one DC voltage out and 90 - 250 VAC input.   That is safe to use.

Comment: All you should need is the plug adapter. The 2.0 amp rating on the adapter is the *maximum* current that can safely pass thru the plug adapter, but your AC -> DC power supply will *only draw the current it needs*. The fact that the power supply's rating is specified as a range means it can work with U.S. line voltage (110/120v) or European (220v). When I traveled to Turkey, I bought the appropriate plug converter and used it with a smilarly rated power supply without incident.

Comment: Just saw the added pics. You should be fine. The *maximum* current that can safely pass thru your power cable/adapter combination is 2.5 amps (limited by the adapter). Your power supply only draws 1.8 amps. ` 1.8 < 2.5 `, so you're good to go.

Comment: Please add a photo of where the mains cable goes into the adapter so that we can be sure, but the best, safest, way is to get a replacement cable which fits an EU socket and the mains input socket on the adapter. There is no need for a US-to-EU plug adapter.

Comment: thank you guys. all of your information is very helpful 

Comment: got it @AndrewMorton , the adapter still on delivery. when it arrives, I will show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fine with the adapter you bought.

The ratings on the adapter and cable specify the *maximums*current that can safely pass thru them. The combination is limited by the lowest rated component, in this case the adapter, so the *maximum* limit for the cable/adapter combo is 2.5 amps.

The rating on the power supply species the maximum current it *draws*: 1.8 amps.

So, because the current drawn by the power supply is below the cable/adapter combo maximun, you're good to go.

The fact that the power supply's rating is specified as a range means it can work with U.S. line voltage (110/120v) or European (220v). I used my U.S. purchased laptop/power supply(similarly rated) in Turkey with only a plug adapter and everything was fine.

Comment: noted. thank you sir. now i fell safe